# Javascript - Return Promise at the end of recursion function with delay

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I am very new to javascript and trying to create a recursion function in Javascript which should return a promise at the end of the recursion. But, with the below code snippet, I am getting the promise returned on the single iteration.

```
function delayedIteration(i) {
    var promises = [];
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if(i >= 10) {
            return;
        }
        console.log("i: "+i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(delayedIteration.bind({}, i), 3000);
        resolve("resolve");
    });
    promises.push(promise);
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

I also tried adding,

```
setTimeout(promises.push(delayedIteration.bind({}, i)), 3000);
```

But, it doesn't help either. Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: when is the end of the recursion ? I don't see a condition to stop it (and yes, since setTimeout is run "in parallel", `resolve` is called before the timeout has reached its end)

Comment: Do you understand that `setTimeout()` is non-blocking?  So, when you execute `return Promise.all(promises)`, there's only ONE promise in that array and it's only that one promise that `Promise.all()` will wait on.  It doesn't affect that `Promise.all()` in any way to call `delayedIteration()` again internally.

Comment: infinite recursion (though no stack issues) - I can't even imagine what this sort of code could possibly be useful for

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the recursion condition. Added it now.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ya, I agree we have only one promise to wait on in the above sample. Hence, I tried adding `setTimeout(promises.push(delayedIteration.bind({}, i)), 3000);` but this also doesn't work.

Comment: To return a promise that resolves when all your recursion is done, you need to CHAIN the subsequent promises to your initial one, not use `Promise.all()`.  Look up promise chaining if you want more info on that.  Chaining will work with an indefinite number of promises.  `Promise.all()` will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the promises returned by the recursive function calls using their then methods, like this:

```js
function delayedIteration(max, i = max + 1) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (i === 1) {
            resolve();
            return;
        }
        delayedIteration(max, --i).then(() =>
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(i);
                resolve();
            }, 3000)
        );
    })
}
delayedIteration(10);
```

Note that I'm counting from the max to 1 here, because the promises that are at the end of the chained then statements are resolved first (there's probably lots of possibilities to optimize this code )

See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pahund/q4cuwse9/

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was out of town. Thanks this helped in achieving the desired output. But, it executes this method first 10 times asynchronously and then it executes those recursive calls. Hence, it gives the same output twice except for i == 1. In Jsfiddle too, if you check the browser console output, you would find the same thing.

Comment: There was a bug in the code, I've fixed it, it works now. I had accidentally switched max and i in the recursive call of delayedIteration

Answer (score 0):

Promises return immediately but resolve later.
A promise basically encapsulates a 'future result' to a function.

Comment: ok. But, is it possible somehow to return after the promise resolves for all recursive function calls?

Comment: The only way you can 'pause' a function and wait for asynchronous code to complete is using async and await.

Comment: But, is it possible to have async and await and return a promise at the end of recursion? I want to somehow return promise as the function caller expects it to be. Thanks

Comment: A function marked as `async` _always_ returns a promise.

Comment: Note that even with async functions, that promise returns immediately though. There is simply no way around it. Any function that is called returns something immediately.